# Differentiation of dirac delta function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, tensors, dirac-delta

While solving some problem i encounter the following step. Given
$$
T^{\mu\nu}_{,\nu}=\sum_i m_i\int d\tau_i U^{\mu}_i U^{\nu}_i \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^{\nu}}}\delta^4[x-x_i(\tau_i)]$$

The delta function depends only on $x -x_i$ so we can replace $
\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^{\nu}}}$  by  $ -\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^{\nu}_i}}$

Can anyone explain why there is a $\textbf{negative sign}$ while changing from $
\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^{\nu}}}$ to $ \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^{\nu}_i}}$ ?

Comment: Let $f$ be a differentiable function. Do you understand why $f'(x-y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x-y)$?

Comment: @md2perpe yes sir, in fact that's what i was expecting, but please notice an extra minus sign

Comment: Of course I made a mistake. I meant to write
$$f'(x-y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-y) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x-y)$$
Note the minus sign here. Do you understand why this is valid for a function?

Comment: yes sir, i understood. for any arbritrary function,but for delta function it would have become x=y, then how come there is an extra minus sign?

Comment: I understand how you think and am trying to find an explanation why it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\varphi(y) = \int \delta(x-y) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \{ x = y+z \}
= \int \delta(z) \, \varphi(y+z) \, dz
.
$$

Therefore, we have
$$
\varphi'(y) = \int \partial_y(\delta(x-y)) \, \varphi(x) \, dx \\
$$
but also
$$
\varphi'(y) = \int \delta(z) \, \partial_y(\varphi(y+z)) \, dz
= \int \delta(z) \, \varphi'(y+z) \, dz
= \{ x = y+z \}
= \int \delta(x-y) \, \varphi'(x) \, dx \\
= - \int \partial_x(\delta(x-y)) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
.
$$

Therefore, $\partial_y(\delta(x-y)) = - \partial_x(\delta(x-y)).$