# Partial derivative of a 1-dimensionnal Dirac delta of 2 variables

Tags: distribution-theory

The problem is very simple, but I'm not sure of the result. I have the function $f(x,y)$ in the Euclidian plan and two constants $(a,b)$:

$ f(x,y) = \delta(a x + b y) $

Now I need the partial derivative of this Dirac delta's. Are these following results corrects (using [Differentiation of dirac delta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713756/differentiation-of-dirac-delta-function): I think yes)?:

$ \partial_{x} f(x,y) \stackrel{?}{=}  a \delta(a x + b y) \partial_{x} \\
 \partial_{x} f(x,y) \stackrel{?}{=}  b \delta(a x + b y) \partial_{y}$

Thank you for reading.

Comment: $\partial_x f(x,y) = a \delta'(ax+by).$

Comment: Ok thanks. And then: $\delta'(ax + b y) = \delta(ax + b y) \partial / \partial{(ax + by)}$ ? Just as $\delta'(x) = \delta(x) \partial / \partial{x}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean with $\partial(ax+by)$ and $\partial x$?

Comment: I mean derivative from $(ax + b y)$ and derivative from $x$.

So I guess (keeping your notation): $\partial{x} \delta(ax + b y)  = a \delta(ax + b y)  ( \frac{1}{b} \partial{y} + \frac{1}{a} \partial{x} )$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "derivative from $(ax+by)$". And what you write is my notation is not my notation.

Comment: I'm not clear I'm sorry. Let's take the product of functions:

$h(x,y) = \partial_x ( \delta(a x + b y) ) g(x,y)$

Now using properties of Dirac delta and integration by part I have:

$\int \partial_x ( \delta(a x + b y) ) g(x,y) d x = \left[ \delta(a x + b y) g(x,y) \right] - \int \delta(a x + b y) \partial_x g(x,y) d x  $ 

Because first term on right side is null:

$\int \partial_x ( \delta(a x + b y) ) g(x,y) d x  = - \int \delta(a x + b y) \partial_x g(x,y) d x $

1/2

Comment: What does $\partial{x}$ mean? Should it be $\partial_x$?

Comment: So we have in principle (I am a physicist, not rigorous sorry): 

$ \partial_x ( \delta(a x + b y) ) g(x,y) = - \delta(a x + b y) \partial_x g(x,y) $ ?

2/2

Comment: Write `\partial_x` to get $\partial_x$.

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for that. 

So this is what I find finally: 

$ \partial_x ( \delta(a x + b y) ) g(x,y) = - \delta(a x + b y) \partial_x g(x,y) $

Comment: That is not correct. The correct formula is $g\delta'=g(0)\delta'-g'\delta.$

Comment: Ok thank you, so if I resume you said:

$ g(x,y) \delta'(a x + b y) = g(0,0)  \delta'(a x + b y)  - g'(x,y) \delta(a x + b y) $ ?

That seems strange

Comment: No, the formula I gave is valid for one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets come back to the basis ... a distribution $T$ is rigorously defined as a linear form on smooth test functions with compact support, i.e. to any test function $\varphi$, it associates a number $T(\varphi) =\langle T,\varphi\rangle$.
For instance **if $T=f$ is a "classical" function** then its distribution is characterized by the fact that for any smooth function $\varphi$, $$\langle T,\varphi\rangle = ∫_{\mathbb R} f\,\varphi.$$
The main point is that it allows to generalize functions to more general distributions, such as the Dirac delta (which I denote by $\delta_0$) verifying $\langle\delta_0,\varphi\rangle = \varphi(0)$. One can then generalize a lot of formulas doing as if the braket was just the integral of a product of functions. For instance, the integration by parts formula allows to define the derivative of a distribution, and the change of variable in integrals allows to change variable in the distribution, so $T'$ and $T(ax)$ are defined by
$$
\langle T',\varphi\rangle = -\langle T,\varphi'\rangle
\\
\langle T(ax),\varphi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{|a|}\,\langle T,\varphi(\tfrac{x}{a})\rangle
$$
In the case of a two variables distribution, one should use two variables test functions (so $\varphi = \varphi(x,y)$). In particular, for $a≠0$ one can define $T(ax+by)$ by
$$\tag{1}
\langle T(ax+by),\varphi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{|a|} \langle T(x),\varphi(\tfrac{x-by}{a},y)\rangle
$$

- In particular we deduce that $\langle\delta_0(ax+by),\varphi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{|a|} \int_{\mathbb R} \varphi(\tfrac{-by}{a},y) \,\mathrm d y$, and so $$\langle\delta_0(ax+by),\varphi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} \varphi(-by,ay) \,\mathrm d y$$
- From $(1)$, we also obtain that since $\langle \partial_x T,\varphi\rangle = -\langle T,\partial_x\varphi\rangle$,
  $$\tag{2}
  \langle \partial_x(T(ax+by)),\varphi\rangle = -\tfrac{1}{|a|} \langle T(x),(\partial_x\varphi)(\tfrac{x-by}{a},y)\rangle \\= -\tfrac{1}{|a|} \langle T(x),a\,\partial_x(\varphi(\tfrac{x-by}{a},y))\rangle
  = \tfrac{1}{|a|} \langle a\,T'(x),\varphi(\tfrac{x-by}{a},y)\rangle
  $$
  which proves that the formula $\partial_x(T(ax+by)) = a \,T'(ax+by)$ remains valid for distributions. Hence
  $$
  \boxed{\partial_x(\delta_0(ax+by)) = a \,\delta_0'(ax+by)
  \\
  \partial_y(\delta_0(ax+by)) = b \,\delta_0'(ax+by)}
  $$
- If you want the action on test functions, then from $(2)$ we see that
  $$
  \langle \partial_x(\delta_0(ax+by)),\varphi\rangle = - \int_{\mathbb R} (\partial_x\varphi)(-by,ay)\, \mathrm d y = - \tfrac{a}{b}\int_{\mathbb R} (\partial_y\varphi)(-by,ay))\, \mathrm d y
  $$

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. The equation (1) was really not intuitive for me. The bracket notation is synthetic and usefull. I only knew about the one variable integration by part propertie: $<T',\varphi> = - <T,\varphi'>$.